# R14 ADT isn't applied for project I cloned from GitHub

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I just cloned a project from GitHub and noticed that R14 preview ADT features aren't applied to it. I can't even see `Graphical Layout` for layout xmls. I'm working under Eclipse, can you suggest where to check why older version of ADT was applied?

Update: When I create a new project I have xml formatting and other things of ADT 14, but if I copy xmls files from that project to this new one I don't have these possibilities again. More to say - if I create new xmls in the same folder with 'problem' xmls they are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's an issue of ADT 14 which is just a preview finally. I installed ADT 13 and everything works just fine.